# Установка уровня звука с помощью Qt

Tags: qt5

Как средствами Qt можно изменить уровень громкости воспроизводимого или записываемого звука?

Comment: Например у QMediaPlayer есть параметр volume

Comment: Да, но при этом не изменяется положение системного регулятора звука. Экспериментально выяснил, что setVolume задает верхнюю границу "системного" уровня, а на нее накладывается уже положение системного регулятора. Т.е. если я задам с помощью setVolume уровень 0.5, а системный будет установлен на половине, то уровень записываемого звука будет ~0.25. Хотелось бы установить уровень именно того, что записывается.

Comment: Насколько я пониманию уровень громкости звука в файл не записывается. При воспроизведении надо регулировать системный уровень звука и уровень конкретного медиа-приложения  отдельно, что собственно, логично, иначе любое медиа приложение устанавливало системное значение так как ему надо, наплевав на другие приложения )

Comment: Вы правы, но я уже говорил, что с помощью setVolume устанавливается максимальный уровень записываемого сигнала, а затем , как я выяснил экспериментальным путем, накладывается уровень системного регулятора. Т.е. пользователь, во время записи, с помощью системного регулятора уровня может изменить уровень сигнала - чего не хотелось бы. Во всяком случае я такое увидел при проведении эксперимента.

Comment: А вы хотите заблокировать системный регулятор? Лучше скажите пользователю, чтобы он во время записи ничего не трогал

Comment: Можно конечно и так...
Но хотелось бы владеть ситуацией в полном объеме :-)